# Como representar um relacionamento N:N em java?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, classes, modelagem

Acredito que seja uma dúvida bem simples, mas não consegui encontrar nenhum exemplo que deixasse isso claro.
Já fiz o meu modelo de banco de dados no PostGreSQL e na hora de criar as classes fiquei um pouco perdida. Eu tenho as entidades Lista (armazena os filmes favoritos do usuário) e Filme (que armazena os dados do filme) e existe um relacionamento N:N entre essas entidades, ou seja, vários filmes podem estar associados à varias listas e vice-versa. Criei uma tabela ListaXFilme que vai ter 2 chaves estrangeiras (uma pra identificar o filme outra pra identificar a lista) e a chave primária dessa tabela vai ser composta pelas 2 chaves estrangeiras. Acho que até aí fiz certo...
Minha dúvida é como faço pra criar classes que representam esse relacionamento.

Os scripts das tabelas que mencionei:

```
CREATE TABLE app.tb_lista_favoritos(
id SERIAL NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
data_criacao DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_lista_favoritos PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE app.tb_filme(
cod SERIAL NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
data_lancamento DATE NOT NULL,
genero VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
duracao TIME NOT NULL,
avaliacao REAL NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_filme PRIMARY KEY (cod)
);

CREATE TABLE app.tb_listaXfilme(
id_lista INT NOT NULL,
cod_filme INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_listaXfilme PRIMARY KEY (id_lista,cod_filme),
CONSTRAINT fk1_listaXfilme FOREIGN KEY (id_lista) REFERENCES app.tb_lista_favoritos (id),
CONSTRAINT fk2_listaXfilme FOREIGN KEY (cod_filme) REFERENCES app.tb_filme (cod)
);
```

Classes:

**ListaFavoritos.java:**

```
public class ListaFavoritos {
    int codLista;
    String nomeLista;
    Date dataCriacao;

    public ListaFavoritos(int codLista, String nomeLista, Date dataCriacao) {
        this.codLista = codLista;
        this.nomeLista = nomeLista;
        this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
    }

    public ListaFavoritos() {

    }

    /*Getters e Setters*/
}
```

**Filme.java:**

```
public class Filme {
    int codFilme;
    double avaliacao;
    Date anoLancamento,duracao;
    String nome, genero;

    public Filme(int codFilme, double avaliacao, Date anoLancamento, Date duracao, String nome, String genero) {
        this.codFilme = codFilme;
        this.avaliacao = avaliacao;
        this.anoLancamento = anoLancamento;
        this.duracao = duracao;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public Filme() {
    }

    /*Getters e setters*/

}
```

Comment: Você está usando alguma camada de Persistência (`Hibernate`) ou `JDBC`?

Comment: Não... pode me explicar do que se trata e como me ajudaria? Não tenho nenhuma experiência com isso

Comment: Se disse que montou as estruturas, as classes etc, se pode postar isso.?

Comment: @Éowyn Hibernate/JDBC são frameworks desenvolvidos para ajudar em algumas ocasiões, mais utilizadas para a manipulação Entidade - Banco, com ele você consegue "mapear" as entidades e definir qual atributo se refere a certa coluna. Algum tutorial basico na internet te mostraria como fazer isso.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nisso. Obrigada! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em banco de dados, relacionamento n pra n gera outra tabela intermediária para armazenar os ids de ambos os lados.

Quando pensamos em objetos, fica um pouco diferente.

Nesse caso faz sentido na classe ListaFavoritos ter um atributo que armazene uma lista de Filmes, ficando assim:

Filme.java:

```
public class Filme {
    int codFilme;
    double avaliacao;
    Date anoLancamento,duracao;
    String nome, genero;

    public Filme(int codFilme, double avaliacao, Date anoLancamento, Date duracao, String nome, String genero) {
        this.codFilme = codFilme;
        this.avaliacao = avaliacao;
        this.anoLancamento = anoLancamento;
        this.duracao = duracao;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public Filme() {
    }

    /*Getters e setters*/

}
```

ListaFavoritos.java

```
public class ListaFavoritos {
    int codLista;
    String nomeLista;
    Date dataCriacao;
    List<Filme> filmes;

    public ListaFavoritos(int codLista, String nomeLista, Date dataCriacao, List<Filme> filmes) {
        this.codLista = codLista;
        this.nomeLista = nomeLista;
        this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
        this.filmes = filmes;
    }

    public ListaFavoritos() {

    }

    /*Getters e Setters*/
}
```

Comment: Verdade! Eu tinha pensado nisso mas estava com medo de fugir do modelo que fiz. Obrigada por esclarecer :)